# how to write bunch of pages efficently using angular js ng-route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I want to add more pages approximately to 100 so how can I write the below code? I just want the shortcut of "when" which is given below. I don't want to write the "when" 100 times.

```
var module = angular.module("sampleApp", ['ngRoute']);

module.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/route1', {
                templateUrl: 'angular-route-template-1.jsp',
                controller: 'RouteController'
            }).
            when('/route2', {
                templateUrl: 'angular-route-template-2.jsp',
                controller: 'RouteController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }]);

module.controller("RouteController", function($scope) {

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.config(['$routeProvider', 'routes'

  function($routeProvider, routes) {
    // routes is the list of my routes
    // e.g. 
    //  routes = [{
    //    url: '/about',
    //    options: {
    //      templateUrl: '/about.html',
    //      controller: 'AboutController as vm',
    //    }
    //  }]

    routes.forEach(function(route) {
      $routeProvider.when(route.url, route.options);
    });

    $routeProvider.
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
  }
]);
```

Comment: when('/about', {
                templateUrl: 'about.jsp'
            }).
            when('/contact', {
                templateUrl: 'contact.jsp'
            }).

Comment: like "about" and "contact" i want add multiple templates with different name. So i want to ask is there any way to write the above code shortly. I don't want to write it 100 times.

Comment: you need to have this list of routes somewhere, otherwise how can you make a loop on it? It can also be a previous request to server, but you need to start from a list

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use the [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/tutorial/ng1/helloworld) module to achieve this more cleanly.

```
var myApp = angular.module('helloworld', ['ui.router']);

myApp.config(function($stateProvider) {
  var helloState = {
    name: 'hello',
    url: '/hello',
    template: '<h3>hello world!</h3>'
  }

  var aboutState = {
    name: 'about',
    url: '/about',
    template: '<h3>Its the UI-Router hello world app!</h3>'
  }

  $stateProvider.state(helloState);
  $stateProvider.state(aboutState);
});
```

You can save your 100 'state' objects inside an array (perhaps even in its own js file), and loop them through the `$stateProvider.state(stateObject);`.